# Angular validator pattern regex for matching one or another rule but not both

Tags: regex, angular

I'm trying to match user ranges with angular validators like this:

[image]

the idea is to match one of two ranges options with an angular pattern validator:

`1-99` or `1,2,5,6,8` but not both `(1-99,101,105,110)` or `(1,3,5,6,7-15)`

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      loads: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d+-\d+|\d+(?:,\d+)*$/)]],
      notes: ['', Validators.required]
    });
```

I've tried some solutions and the most closest was this one, but it matched both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a working solution:

```
Validators.pattern(/^\d+-\d+$|^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/)
```

I needed to start and end the assert in each option of the OR:

```
1,2,3,4,5-99       // not match
1-99,1,23,3,4,5    // not match
1-99               // matches
1,2,3,4,5          // matches
```